# Having composite and primary keys in SQL table

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key

I am having a problem with creating SQL table with composite and primary keys in it. This is what I have for now:

```
CREATE TABLE Racunar (
  IPAdresa char(15) PRIMARY KEY,
  CPU char(20),
  HD char(20)
);

CREATE TABLE Program (
  Naziv char(15),
  Verzija char(20),
  Datum char(11),
  PRIMARY KEY(Naziv, Verzija)
);

CREATE TABLE Operater (
  SifO int PRIMARY KEY,
  Ime char(20),
  BrTel char(20)
);

CREATE TABLE JeInstaliran (
  IPAdresa char(15) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Racunar(IPAdresa),
  SifO int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Operater(SifO),
  FOREIGN KEY(Naziv, Verzija) REFERENCES Program(Naziv, Verzija),
  DatumInstalacije char(11)
);
```

The problem is somewhere in the last table. I am using [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and it returned the next error message after trying to build schema:

> Schema Creation Failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Racunar(IPAdresa),
>   SifO int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Oper' at line 2:

I don't know why this doesn't work, so I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like the JeInstaliran table is trying to use columns it doesn't have as a key (Naviz, Verzija).  Try defining those columns first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is incorrect. Instead of defining the `FOREIGN KEY` along with the column, define it after the column definition using the syntax `FOREIGN KEY (colname) REFERENCES tablename (foreign_colname)`

```
CREATE TABLE JeInstaliran (
  IPAdresa char(15),
  SifO int,
  Naziv char(15),
  Verzija char(20),
  FOREIGN KEY (IPAdresa) REFERENCES Racunar(IPAdresa),
  FOREIGN KEY (SifO) REFERENCES Operater(SifO),
  FOREIGN KEY(Naziv, Verzija) REFERENCES Program(Naziv, Verzija),
  DatumInstalacije char(11)
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Corrected my code and it now works. This is how the last table looks like now:

    CREATE TABLE JeInstaliran (
      IPAdresa char(15),
      Naziv char(15),
      Verzija char(15),
      SifO int,
      DatumInstalacije char(11),
      FOREIGN KEY(Naziv, Verzija) REFERENCES Program(Naziv, Verzija),
      FOREIGN KEY(IPAdresa) REFERENCES Racunar(IPAdresa),
      FOREIGN KEY(SifO) REFERENCES Operater(SifO)
    );

Comment: @Catcall an oversight, corrected above, and  corrected in the OP's working version.